# Cost of services on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I've recently deployed my first project and I am using some AWS services e.g. ECR, ECS...

I've been monitoring my cost so far, and with 0 traffic it's about $2-3 per day and I'm wondering is this a reasonable cost for what I am using?

I have 1 cluster with 3 ECS services (each service starts with 1 container with 0.25vCPU/0.5GB memory) running 24/7. From reading my bill the other services like Route 53 etc. are minimal and most of my cost comes from these ECS instances.

Is the cost of AWS for small projects notoriously high? I'm hoping that once I begin taking on users and possibly allocating more resources to my services I won't have to migrate providers due to cost increases.

Thanks

Comment: I would say that 2-3$ is a bit too high: https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/ - you should end up with `(0,04048*24*0,25+0,004445*24*0,5)*3 = ~0,88$` per day (may vary depending on the region). The AWS cost explorer should give you more insight into which services cost how much exactly.

Answer (score 2):

AWS is pretty transparent on pricing, so check what are you using and the pricing for each.

In your case, assuming you're using Fargate which it's what I understand by the context of your question, 3 containers with 0.25vCPU and 0.5GB each running 24/7 should cost $0.88.

How are you accessing those services? do you have an ALB in front of them? Are you sure there is only one replica per service? Have you set up autoscaling? Many variables that only you can answer.

You need to clearly know what are you using. This sentence `I am using some AWS services e.g. ECR, ECS...` ending in `...` is not appropriate. Find out what are you using, and then you will understand where is that bill coming from.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the ALB too. It does take some cost, it should only add an extra $0.55/day. 

Each hour figure is different. Memory hours 775, CPU hours 285 and ALB 326 hours, should these not all be similar?

Calculating my hours against the Fargate pricing on docs, my bill is correct to my usage but obviously there must be something bumping the hours that I will need to investigate myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ECS itself is not something you pay for, you pay for the resources you use such as EC2 instances...
ECS is just a service that help you deploy your environment.
You can choose for example to run your service with few resources, let say 1 t2.micro instance or 10 t3a.2xlarge instances.
The cost will be according to the resources you use.